# validate a jwt token without jwt secret using private key and public key

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, private-key

I want to create an express API (let's name it *MASTER*) that can authorize users of another API (let's name it *SLAVE*). I have a JWT secret in *MASTER API* which I create JWT tokens with, and send them to *SLAVE API*'s users. I want the *SLAVE API* to be able to validate *MASTER API*'s token, without knowing the JWT secret.

I think it can be accomplished with private key public key and packages like [jwks-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa) but I don't know the exact logic behind it. How to generate the public key / private key and how does the exact flow work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the asymmetric part in https://www.pingidentity.com/en/company/blog/posts/2019/jwt-security-nobody-talks-about.html                                                                                                                               This will give an idea of the flow of public/private key in JWT.                                                       Check other resources on how to generate the public/private keys.